# how to set pagination in django views?

Tags: sql, django, django-rest-framework, pagination

how to set pagination in this function based views, i tried all the default django_pagination but i didn't get any helped.

```
class Order_ListAPIView(APIView):

   def get(self,request,format=None):

       if request.method == 'GET':
           cur,conn = connection()
           order_query = ''' SELECT * FROM orders'''
           order_detail_query = ''' SELECT * FROM order_details'''

           with conn.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cursor:

               cursor.execute(order_query)
               order_result = cursor.fetchall()
               order_data = list(order_result)

           ...
            ... #rest_code
             ...


           return Response({"order_data":order_data},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
       else:
           return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Answer (score 0):

As a suggessiton, you can use django-rest-framework generic [views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#generic-views), [paginations](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#modifying-the-pagination-style) and django [orm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/).

paginations.py

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination
class OrderPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 20 #default
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from .paginations import OrderPagination
from .models import Order

class OrderListAPIView(ListAPIView):
   serializer_class = your_serializer_class
   pagination_class = OrderPagination
   queryset = Order.objects.all()
```